# ASP.NET Core MVC как получить значения из Postgre?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core

```
public class Product
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public ProductContext(DbContextOptions<ProductContext> options) : base(options){}
}
```

Мне нужно получить значения из БД ProductsDB, для того чтобы вывести список товаров на сайт.
БД я подключил в appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "User ID=postgres;Password=123;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=productsdb;Pooling=true;"
  },
```

В Startup в ConfigureServices:

```
    string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<ProductContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(connection));
```

При обращении к test() - выдает пустой JSON:

```
 private readonly ProductContext _context;

        public Category(ProductContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("category/test")]
        public IActionResult test()
        {
            var result = _context.Products.ToList();
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Может я что-то забыл или сделал неправильно?

Comment: в базе данные есть?

Comment: @tym32167 в базе есть 5 записей

Comment: замените `_context = context;` на `_context = new ProductContext("User ID=postgres;Password=123; .... ваша строка соединения ");` и проверьте

Comment: @tym32167 Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "string" в "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<Projj.Models.ProductContext>"

Comment: у вас asp.net core?

Comment: @tym32167 да. В топике указывал его.

Comment: по идее все должно работать. У вас вообще ваш код вызывается во время запроса?

Comment: @tym32167 да. вызывается.